# How to bypass password validation in the following OmniAuth login method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, omniauth

I have some password validation for my `User` model, and a `create_with_omniauth` method to get the information from the user's Facebook account:

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_secure_password

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
      user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
    end
  end
end
```

Now when I click `link_to "Sign in with Facebook, "auth/facebook"` I get this error:

> Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password can't be blank,
>   Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters), Password confirmation
>   can't be blank

Because of this two lines in the `User` model:

```
 validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
 validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

How to bypass that validation when the user is trying to log in with the OmniAuth login method?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This can be done in 2 ways .

1) Just save a random secure generated number in the password field (better because it's easy and also to maintain the consistency) personally I have applied this method as the users who have signed through a social site will not login through site login.

2) Or, use an `attr_accesor`

```
 :login_social (will be treated as boolean  
 validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, :if => !login_social?
 validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, :if => :login_social?
```

Whenever logging through any social site just make this field true. I followed the second method then turned to the first solution as it was better.

Personally I suggest you go for the first method

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestions! Sorry, I'm a Rails beginner. Could you give me an example of the code to generate the random password when the user clicks the Facebook sign in?

Comment: self.password = self.password_confirmation = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(n=6)

Comment: Thanks! So that should go in the `self.create_with_omniauth` method? Shouldn't it be then `user.password`?

Comment: creating a secure random password is extremely easy, as stated and shown a few comments above.  Highly recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

As @Aayush suggested to create a field to detect social login, then instead of creating your own validation you can
override this devise method:

```
 def password_required?
     self.social_login? ? false : super
 end
```

in your model e.g `User`

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this is to add a simple password to omniauth users, and make it impossible to sign in with those passwords if Rails detects that they are omniauth users. This simplifies my User model as I can still use has_secure_password, and makes the password irrelevant (and impossible to use) if they use a social login.

My User database table has the following:

- name
- email
- password
- password_confirmation
- uid
- provider

sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  if auth
    sign_in_with_auth(auth)
  else
    sign_in_with_password
  end
end
```

sessions_helper.rb

```
def sign_in_with_auth(auth)
  user = User.find_by(uid: auth['uid'])
  if user
    #sign in the user
  else
    #create a user with any password.
    user = User.create! do |user|
      ...
      user.password = 'bojanglesicedtea'
      user.password_confirmation = 'bojanglesicedtea'
      user.provider = auth['provider']
    end
    #then sign in the user
  end
end

def sign_in_with_password
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:sessions][:email].downcase)
  if user == user.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password]) && user.provider.nil?
    #sign in the user
    #user.provider.nil? will be true only if it is not a social login user
  else
    #direct to error notification
  end
end
```

Comment: just for someone who might need this, if you are using has_secure_password and you have validations for password then you must provide the password. This worked for me when i used the omniauth google oauth2 gem.

Comment: Please do not set a static password. It should be randomized so that it cannot be compromised in some way.